# How can I run multiple JARs in Dockerfile?

Tags: java, dockerfile

I have a simple Java code with three main classes. I want to build 3 different JARs out of it and then add those JARs to my Dockerfile and call each JAR in a different Docker image. How can I do it?

Comment: You probably mean 3 _different Docker containers_ of the _same Docker image_. Is it right?

Comment: No, 3 different docker container running 3 different docker images.

Comment: So, why not just write 3 Dockerfiles, instead of one?

Comment: My requirement is to run in a single Dockerfile

Comment: @Alirus 3 different Dockerfile is a good idea, but can I run in a single Dockerfile??

Comment: Docker currently supports multi-stage builds, but does not allow you to create multiple images (separated by tags/names).

Comment: @Alirus Better I should go with 3 Dockerfile for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Adding bash script to execute multiple commands and blocks:**

```
#start.sh
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar MyFirst.jar &
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar MySecond.jar
... etc
```

**Change your Dockerfile:**

```
# base image is java:8 (ubuntu)
FROM java:8

    # add files to image 
    ADD first.jar .
    ADD second.jar .
    ...
    ADD start.sh .

    # start on run
    CMD ["bash", "start.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The Docker `run` command accepts an optional `COMMAND` argument. You can simply add 3 JARs to the Docker image and specify which to run via Docker command.

On the other hand, if you're willing to create multiple images of a single Dockerfile, docker currently supports multi-stage builds (that actually create multiple images) but does not allow you to tag every one of them.

Comment: No, 3 different docker container running 3 different docker images.

Comment: if I add 3 jars in a single Dockerfile and try to run them individually, it always results in an output of the last added jar.

Comment: ^ Had the same issue... found this. [If a Dockerfile has multiple CMDs, it only applies the instructions from the last one.](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-cmd-vs-entrypoint#:~:text=Docker%20Entrypoint%20vs%20CMD%3A%20Solving%20the%20Dilemma.%20In,only%20applies%20the%20instructions%20from%20the%20last%20one.)